# On the console I'm getting an 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning'

Tags: javascript, automation, cucumber, cucumberjs

```
0-0] 2020-05-13T02:50:41.196Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to invalid session id: invalid session id
    [0-0] (node:80394) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: invalid session id

        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
        at ElementUtil.doGetText (/Users/arjitrout/Downloads/BasicReport 3/test/util/elementUtil.js:13:20)
        at ShopPage.getCategoryTitle (/Users/arjitrout/Downloads/BasicReport 3/test/pages/shop.page.js:13:27)
        at World.<anonymous> (/Users/arjitrout/Downloads/BasicReport 3/test/stepDefination/shop/popularCategories.stepdefs.js:27:35)
    [0-0] (node:80394) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
    (node:80394) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    [0-0] FAILED in chrome - /test/features/shop/popularCategories.feature
```

Comment: "'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning'" means you didn't provide a catch method to deal with promise rejection

Comment: @SaymoinSam


When('Popular categories block is present in config json',(name) => {

  const currentImage = imagePath({ base: currentDirectory, name });
  const referenceImage = imagePath({ base: referenceDirectory, name });
  if (referenceRun || !fs.existsSync(referenceImage)) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.info(`INFO: Reference image successfully created: ${referenceImage}`);
    client.saveScreenshot(referenceImage);
  }

  return client.saveScreenshot(currentImage);


});

Comment: This is my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, you have an issue with your session id. You may want to check [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/InvalidSessionID) to know more about it.

As for the `Unhandled Promise` error,  Usually, this error is thrown when an exception occurs inside a `Promise` when you don't provide a `catch` clause and [`window.unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) is not defined, but I bet it's related to the `invalid session id` issue in this particular case. You can try to fix that first, then see if that solves both problems.